# Jmeter-server4.0 using ipv6

Tags: jmeter, ipv6, nat, ipv4, jmeter-4.0

I have setup Jmeter Server on my local linux server (192.168.10.132)

I have started it with "jmeter-server" in my install dir "/opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin/bin/"

[image]

(The default port for Jmeter Server is 1099 - [Link to Doc](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange))

When I try to connect the GUI version on my Windows 10 machine I get:
[image]

On my local server (192.168.10.132) when I use "lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN" I see the port **1099** "listening" yet in IPV**6** and not IPV**4**.

[image]

How can I change the IPV6 to IPV4?

*To add detail to Dmitri's reply:*

I have tried 1. setting the following in system.properties and 2. even running jmeter with "*jmeter-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"*

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
java.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false
java.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true
```

[image]

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter server to pick up the change
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for every remote slave and the master node

Another option is to pass the value via -D command-line argument like:

```
jmeter-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

References:

- [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I have tried both to no avail. I have updated my question (see bottom part)